# Shalom Zachar on Pesach Night

Tags: shabbat, passover, pregnancy-birth

[Rav Heinemann](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moshe_Heinemann) mentioned during a shiur that there is no shalom zachar on Pesach if shabbos is the night of the seder. Although practically having one would be very difficult, why is this night halachically different from all other shabbos nights that we don't have a shalom zachar?

Comment: Probably something to do with *leil shimurim* ... if we assume the Shalom Zachor has something to do with guarding the baby (which is one explanation for the minhag).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I thought, like Shalom in the comment, that there was no need to "guard over" the baby on Pesach Night. I have now seen [ohr.edu](https://ohr.edu/ask/ask265.htm) takes a more technical angle

> On the night of Passover, it is forbidden to eat anything after eating
>   the afikomen - the piece of matzah eaten at the end of the Passover
>   seder. Therefore, the shalom zachor, which is usually held after the
>   Friday evening meal, is not held on this night.

(slightly edited for clarity)

Comment: Good point! *Hi, welcome everyone! [Yawn.] We have um ... water ... and um ... seltzer ... and um ... yeah that's about all we're allowed to serve right now.*

Comment: @Shalom, coffee (לפי מנהג פיורדא)